# WCF service throttling settings for a proxy gateway

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, concurrency, throttling

We have a WCF service gateway. With a minimal validation, we send the requests to upstream for further processing. This is running on .net 4.7.2

The throttling settings are defined per client dynamically. Most of them have below values.

- **MaxConcurrentCalls** = 16
- **MaxConcurrentInstances** = 16
- **MaxConcurrentSessions** = 10

We see the calls waiting for upstream response longer time... which showing higher latency on our service though there are no blockage in upstream.

We tried increasing all the values to **128**.. still didn't see much improvement.

The prod env has 3 servers each with 10-cores CPU with 32gb ram

[image: Latency]

Questions

- How do I reduce the requests waiting in our queue? (I am checking the current requests for the pool)
- Are there any settings in IIS, that I could use to kill the long waiting requests

Comment: Requests exceeding the limit will be queued. If the WCF application is running in IIS, you can set the **Queue Length** property of the WCF application in the application pool Advanced Settings.

Comment: The QueueLength is at default 1000. I am not seeing those many requests pending. But of the few (<100) requests, I see some are waiting longer in the queue

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.